# What characters in this string throw the error invalid character constant?

Tags: java, android

I'm following an example online, and in one of the lines of code it has this string:

```
Pattern screenNamePattern = Pattern.compile('(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)');
```

When I put it into Eclipse, it throws the error "invalid character constant." What strings in here throw that error? I'm confused...

Comment: `'` is for *character* literals. `"` is for *string* literals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put it in `"double quotes"` instead of `'single quotes'`.

Double quotes are for string literals, single quotes are for single character constants.

Comment: same problem how to fix with character 
char strFrench[] = {'Ã¨', 'Ã©', 'Ãª', 'Ã«', 'Ãº', 'Ã»', 'Ã¹', 'Ã¼', 'Ã¯', 'Ã®', 'Ã ', 'Ã¢', 'Ã´', 'Ã¶', 'Ã§', 'Ã¿', 'Ãˆ', 'Ã‰', 'ÃŠ', 'Ã‹', 'Ãš', 'Ã›', 'Ã™', 'Ãœ', 'Ã�', 'ÃŽ',
     'Ã€', 'Ã‚', 'Ã”', 'Ã–', 'Ã‡', 'ÂŸ', 'Ã ', 'Ã¢', '-' /*, ''', 'Å“', 'Å’'*/};